# Better way to check bounds

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

I am checking to see in an object is outside the bounds of a box.  If it is outside the bounds of the box, then I put it back in.

```
if position.left < dot_radius
    dot.css 'left', dot_radius
if position.left > display_width - dot_radius
    dot.css 'left', display_width - dot_radius
if position.top < dot_radius
    dot.css 'top', dot_radius
if position.top > display_height - dot_radius
    dot.css 'top', display_height - dot_radius
```

The code is a little verbose.  Is there a better way to write it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could make a simple function:

```
bounds = (prop, min, max) ->
    val = position[prop];
    if (val < min)
        dot.css prop, min
    if (var > max)
        dot.css prop, max

bounds 'left', dot_radius, display_width - dot_radius
bounds 'top', dot_radius, display_height - dot_radius
```

You even might put the `dot_radius` inside the function, though it gets less reusable then.